# Unwanted file path with file_get_content

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$file1 = file_get_contents('http://www.mydomain.com/admin/config/main.txt');
echo "<a href='$file1' >";
?>
```

Which give me a hyperlink as follows:

www.mydomain.com/admin/config/'content of main.txt'

All I want is it to create a link which contains 'content of main.txt'

I have tried the following:

```
$file1 = file_get_contents('http://www.mydomain.com/admin/config/main.txt', false);
```

But it just gives me the same back.

I'm lost as to how to just give me whatever is in the file, without the path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to force download the file ?

Comment: Is the contents of the file a link?

Try doing a `<?php die(var_dump($file1)); ?>` to make sure it's reading right.

Comment: if you want to show the file on your domain then you need to put the contents in one file and then give a link to that file

Comment: @Suyash so essentially link to the file ;)

Comment: ohh.. misread.. thought it was an external file.. my bad

Answer (score -1):

Take out the part you don't want to see in the link.

```
<?php 
$file1 = file_get_contents('http://www.mydomain.com/admin/config/main.txt');

$file1_pruned = str_replace('www.mydomain.com/admin/config/','',$file1);

echo "<a href='$file1_pruned' >";

/* When I have this kind of unexpected results, I like to compare 
** the original with the modified result. So you might also show 
** both after the link just to compare.
**/
echo "Checking output.<br><br>file1: $file1<br>file1_modified: $file1_modified";
?>
```